# Why does the establishment of a websocket connection fail for this Go program?

Tags: go, websocket

I am using this ip 192.168.1.55. I need to send some data to 192.168.1.137. I am using this code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
)

func Echo(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Echoing")

    for n := 0; n < 10; n++ {
        msg := "Hello  " + string(n+48)
        fmt.Println("Sending to client: " + msg)
        err := websocket.Message.Send(ws, msg)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't send")
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    http.Handle("http://192.168.1.137", websocket.Handler(Echo))
    http.ListenAndServe(":4242", nil)
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Fatal error ", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

But my ip is not connecting to the other ip which i have mentioned above(192.168.1.137). How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have an error returned by the `http.ListenAndServe` function ?

Answer (score 1):

The path given for handling is wrong. You have to define the route on which the websocket should connect.

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("http://192.168.1.137", websocket.Handler(Echo))
    http.ListenAndServe(":4242", nil)
}
```

should be

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(Echo))
    http.ListenAndServe(":4242", nil)
}
```

You can use [Websocket.org](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

He wants to connect to, not to listen.

```
// you need to make sure this values are correct. and server is listening on "192.168.1.137:4242"
origin := "http://192.168.1.55/"
url := "ws://192.168.1.137:4242"

ws, err := websocket.Dial(url, "", origin)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for n := 0; n < 10; n++ {
    msg := "Hello  " + strconv.Itoa(n)
    fmt.Println("Sending to client: " + msg)
    err := ws.Write([]byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't send")
        break
    }
}
```